# Ruby update tags in rally

Tags: ruby, rally

I use

```
@rally.update("#{type}","#{@object["_ref"]}",field)
```

to update field tags, but it doesn't work. I define `field["Tags"]` as `@tag["_ref"]`.

The whole ruby code is pasted here. http://pastebin.ubuntu.com/6475850/

Comment: Define "doesn't work". What does it do? What do you expect? Also, please don't refer solely to an external link. The pertinent code should be included in the question. If you can reduce the problem to the minimal size, it will be easier for others.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The Tags attribute is a collection in Rally, so even if you're adding just one Tag to an Object, it needs to be in an array:

```
 field["Tags"] = [@tag]
 @rally.update("#{type}","#{@object["_ref"]}",field)
```

Should do the trick. Note however, that the above will *replace* any existing Tags on an Artifact, so it would be a good idea to do something like this:

```
 @object.read
 existing_tags = @object.Tags
 updated_tags = existing_tags
 if !updated_tags.nil? then
     updated_tags.push(@tag)
 else
     updated_tags = [@tag]
 end
 field["Tags"] = updated_tags
 @rally.update("#{type}","#{@object["_ref"]}",field)
```

Comment: That's helpful. Thanks!

Comment: I've tried and it should be updated_tags = [@tag]. If you use [@tag["_ref"]], it won't work. Thanks!

Comment: Thanks! Updated the answer to reflect your fix :)